# Add view to the top view controller

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to add a UIView to the UIView that is currently showing.
This is the code I've come up with:

```
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    UINavigationController *nav = window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *viewController = [[nav viewControllers]lastObject];
    NSLog(@"La clase: %@", [viewController class]);


    [viewController.view addSubview:self.infoMsg];
```

The problem is that I dont see that UIView, the value of the variable `viewController` is correct, but I don't see the view added on that view...

Thanks

[EDIT]

I just checked and If for example instead of add as a subview `infoMsg` which is a UIView that I have syntesized, and I add a UIView that I create just before adding it adds correctly why is that? why can't I add an attribute of my object?

Comment: try adding [viewController.view bringSubviewToFront:self.infoMsg];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to still create the view before adding it, no matter if it's a property or just a local variable. I don't see where you initialize `self.infoMsg`. It's probably `nil`.

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.infoMsg == nil ? @"It's nil" : @"It's not nil");
```

If it's nil, that that's your problem.